# php mysql sum row values starting with MIN and ending at a fixed number

Tags: php, mysql

First, I am querying my database in such a way to only retrieve rows that will add up to a predetermined number starting with the smallest value

```
$value = $_POST['number'];//75
$query = SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.col <= '$value' Order By ASC
```

Request: Then only select and print the rows that sum up to $value starting with the smallest. Adding rows until it reaches 75

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$row = $rows['t.col'];
//need rows that add to 75
echo $row
}
```

Comment: `$row += $rows['t.col'];` `if( $row==75){break;}`

Comment: awesome...but a small problem...if I have three values of 5 and change the $row==5 it shows nothing...$row==10 it shows 5...$row==11 it shows all 15 (all three are added). anything that can be added to make the function more exact?

Comment: you are checking after the calculation?

Comment: Yes...the calculation needs to be equal to the target or be overflow by only one addition...if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should echo out the t.col values untill the sum matches 75

```
<?php
$row = 0;
while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query) ){
    $row += $rows['t.col'];
    // need rows that add to 75
    echo $rows['t.col'];

    if ($row >= 75){
        break; // exit loop
    }
}
```